# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces causes Invalid access to memory location

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, network-interface

I have this piece of code to get a `NetworkInterface` with a specific name:

```
string myIf = "Local Area Connection";
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == myIf);
```

However, this throws a `NetworkInformationException: Invalid access to memory location` with an `ErrorCode` of 998 (which means exactly the same as the exception says).

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException was unhandled  
 ErrorCode=998
 HResult=-2147467259
 Message=Invalid  access to memory location
 NativeErrorCode=998
 Source=System  
 StackTrace:
      at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemNetworkInterface.GetNetworkInterfaces()
      at System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
      at MyApp.CheckIfNetworkOnline(Object state)
      at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
      at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
      at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
      at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()   
 InnerException:
```

.NET documentation claims that this is due to "A Windows system function call failed" or "when a call to a Win32 function fails".

This is on .NET 4.5.2, the network interface does exist, and the application is already running as Administrator.

What can cause this exception to appear, and is there anything that can be done to fix it?

Comment: Install LINQPad and see if simply evaluating the expression `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` is already problematic. If so, you may have a network driver that isn't playing nice in all circumstances. See if `netsh interface show interface` shows anything funky.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Done!

Comment: If, as your method name suggests, you are merely interested in whether a network is available, you may want to use `GetIsNetworkAvailable` instead. You cannot, in general, rely on the appropriate connection being named "Local Area Connection". (On my machine, it's called "Ethernet", but really, it could be anything. All you should care about is that it's not a loopback or tunnel interface and leave the rest to the route table.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I can't use `GetIsNetworkAvailable` because there are several network interfaces on this PC, and I need to check if one particular interface is available and up, not if any interface is up.

Comment: Error code 998 is very, very nasty.  The DllMain entrypoint of an unmanaged DLL failed with an AccessViolationException.  Very much a dirty machine problem, so you'd start by trying this on another machine to verify that this only happens on this one.  Then it could be useful to unable unmanaged debugging and forcing the debugger to stop on a Win32 exception, helps you identify the specific DLL.  Tinkering with the installed anti-malware product tends to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my 32-bit site and following steps solved my problem.

1. Open IIS
2. Expand your machine name on the left
3. Select "Application Pools"
4. Select the Application Pool of your site
5. On the right in the actions select "Advanced Settings"
6. In the General Change "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to false and press OK
7. On the right in the actions select "Advanced Settings" again.
8. In the General Change "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true and press OK